# How does useQuery works internally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, apollo-client

we use useQuery hook in the following way

```
function Dogs({ onDogSelected }) {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_DOGS);

  if (loading) return 'Loading...';
  if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

  return (
    <select name='dog' onChange={onDogSelected}>
      {data.dogs.map((dog) => (
        <option key={dog.id} value={dog.breed}>
          {dog.breed}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

here we are using destructuring assignment syntax and defining a const variable loading and assigning it to the loading property of the useQuery result object. But as loading is of boolean type, hence this variable is assigned according to pass by value, then how this variable changes to false as initially it is true. As the variable is const, so this value should not change. I am not able to understand what happens behind the scenes when useQuery is used?

Comment: The same way a `useState` hook works: by re-rendering the component and re-executing the entire function.

Comment: Your component function is called every time React needs to render your component. Each call to your component function creates a *new* set of local variables/constants (just like any other function). So initially `useQuery` may return `loading = true`, then subsequently when the function is called again, it may return `loading = false`. This is exactly like having `const x = Math.random();` in a function and calling that function twice (except with `useQuery`, it's not random, `useQuery` stores information in your component's instance data -- like `useState`, `useRef`, etc. do.)

Comment: I suggest working through any half-decent React tutorial, which will cover this. (It's not specific to `useQuery`, the basic hooks (such as `useState`) work the same way.) It's not at all unusual to be confused by it at first.

Comment: in useState we set the state explicitly to a new value and it triggers re-rendering of the component but here we are not doing anything except calling it once so how does it triggers the re-render ?

Comment: @KumudRaghav - `useQuery`'s code is setting its state members when the ajax call finishes. Since you've used `useQuery` during in your component function's call, the state members it creates are stored in your component's instance data, and setting them makes your component rerender.

Answer (score 1):

> But as loading is of boolean type, hence this variable is assigned according to pass by value, then how this variable changes to false as initially it is true.

It doesn't. The `loading` const you get during the first call to your component function never changes. But later, when the ajax call finishes, `useQuery` updates a state member, which makes React call your component function again to re-render. In that call, `useQuery` returns a *new* value for the new `loading` const that's specific to that function call. This is just like `useState`, which always returns the up-to-date state value.

> in useState we set the state explicitly to a new value and it triggers re-rendering of the component but here we are not doing anything except calling it once so how does it triggers the re-render ?

That happens because `useQuery` is using and updating state members in its code, ones you only see indirectly via its return value. Since you're calling it during the render call to your component function, those state members are stored in your component instance's state data, so updating them makes your component re-render.

Let's mock it up with our own stand-in for `useQuery` that just waits a moment then returns a random number, so we can see the code doing what the code "hidden" away in `useQuery` is doing (it's not really hidden, it's open source, but...):

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function useDelayedRandom() {
    console.log(`useDelayedRandom: called`);

    const [rand, setRand] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`useDelayedRandom: scheduling timer`);
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
            console.log(`useDelayedRandom: setting rand = ${rand}`);
            setRand(rand);
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }, []);

    return rand
}

const Example = () => {
    console.log(`Example: called`);

    const rand = useDelayedRandom();

    console.log(`Example: rand = ${rand}`);
    
    return (
        <div>rand = { rand }</div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

The `useDelayedRandom` hook waits a second, then generates a random number and does a state update (`setRand(rand)`). That state is held in your component instance (behind the scenes in React's internals), so updating it schedules the re-render.

`useQuery` is doing much the same, but updating in response to the ajax call completing rather than a timer.

Answer (score -2):

The React Query docs at [tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/overview](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/overview) should answer this. Your `<Dogs>` component is (or should be) wrapped in a `<QueryClientProvider>`. I believe this outer `<QueryClientProvider>` is responsible for rerendering your `<Dogs>` component until `useQuery()` returns data.

Comment: The docs don't explain how it works internally.

Comment: This question is regarding Apollo Client, not TanStack Query.